# how to get html source without any error?

Tags: php, html

i want get the html source of a page but give a error!!
i use this code for give:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.google.com/");
    echo $html;
```

when I want to get the source from [here](http://haftegy.ir/category/ax/) I don't correct response and I get something like these characters

```
����i�[S$%ٲ�9������
```

Comment: If you're using simple_html_dom, don't.  It's not useful if you want the actual HTML of the whole page.  At best, it's for grabbing bits of content from the page (but it rather sucks even at that).

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `file_get_contents` instead:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this,note: Download simple_html_dom class [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.co.in');
echo $html;
?>
```